# WooCommerce: delete range of orders using a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

This actually [relates to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904413/how-to-delete-completed-orders-in-woocommerce-using-a-my-sql-query) which shows how completely delete all the completed orders from a WooCommerce store. I want to do something similar, but instead of deleting all the orders, I just want to delete a range of orders. Let's say anything in the range of Order ID 1,000-2,000.

Here's how you do it from the entire database:

```
DELETE FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
DELETE FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_type = 'order_note'
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' )
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
```

How can I do it from a range?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Simple. To clean up the database as it’s pretty large right now. Mostly coming from these orders.

Comment: Memory's so cheap; it just doesn't make sense.