# How do I delete orders from a cloned WooCommerce site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have used NS Cloner to clone site within WooCommerce. This has worked extremely well but the existing orders have been duplicated in the cloned site; I obviously would like remove all of these. In total there are 17,000 or more that I need to remove so doing this in the Admin area isn't an option as it does in 20 batches. There isn't an option to do a bulk delete. I have a suspicion I make have to do this at a mysql level. There is a plugin out there (WC Delete All Orders) but the reviews are less than favourable.

Could some one point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin in order to delete in bulk
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-store-toolkit

Comment: Thanks @loicTheAztec that's a nice looking plugin.

Answer (score 0):

So I used SQL query for this one:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'trash' WHERE post_type = 'shop_order';
```

from this link - [how to delete completed orders in woocommerce using a my sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904413/how-to-delete-completed-orders-in-woocommerce-using-a-my-sql-query)